# What are the little flags sticking up from some helmets in Star Wars supposed to do or be?

Tags: star-wars

Boba Fett and Captain Rex both have these strange flag-like things sticking up from their helmets.

[image: Boba Fett and Captain Rex with a strange protrusion from their helmets]

Are these things radio antennae? It would be strange if they were, because the Clone Troopers communicate with their gauntlet radios. Are these flag/antenna things ever shown to do anything or are they just decoration?

Comment: Why would the fact that they talk through their gloves discount a piece of the helmet from being an antenna? Would you really put an antenna into a glove? :D

Comment: I just thought an antenna on a helmet would allow for helmet communications not gauntlet communications. Idk

Comment: Signaling the mailman?

Comment: @Luaan ...[yes?](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/inspectorgadget/images/e/e1/Inspector-gadget-phone-glove-1.jpg). Although I admit that's not likely Star Wars canon :P

Comment: They are [_Sashimono_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sashimono).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The "flag" houses a holographic scanner and a range-finding sensor which interface with a HUD inside the helmet. The entire whole unit is typically referred to as a '[**rangefinder**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rangefinder)'

> [image]
>
> **Targeting rangefinder (retracted)**
> The helmet tracking sensors sent information directly to the helmet
> displays. It gave Fett precise readings on the speed of, and distance to
> any given target.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Helmet Collection #2](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Helmet_Collection_2)</sup></sub>

and

> **Holographic targeting display**
> When flipped down, the targeting display interfaces with the visor to give tracking information on up to 30 targets at a time.

And, as you can see from these image from *The Empire Strikes Back*, *The Clone Wars*, the flag folds down so that it makes an eyepiece, as can be seen in *Attack of the Clones* when Jango fires his bolo at Obi-Wan.

> [image: Fett with rangefinder down]

> [image]

Comment: There's a scene in The Mandalorian (or multiple) where exactly this happens too (I'm not sure if we see this in the.movies).

Comment: @Peter We see Boba Fett use his in TESB when he's tracking the Falcon, as far as I know that's the only time it's used in the movies.

Comment: @MiloP, In TESB Novelization (not on-screen), Fett uses it also when he's taking Han Solo to his ship and Luke ends up behind them. This is why he ends up shooting at Luke in the corridor in Cloud City.

Answer (score 2):

The little flag is actually a targeting system (known as a [Rangefinder](https://screenrant.com/mandalorian-boba-fett-helmets-targeting-sight-difference-explained/)) for the missile on the back of the [Z-6 Jetpack](https://www.starwars.com/databank/z-6-jetpack) You can see this in the Mandalorian episode entitled "The Marshal (Chapter 9)." The sheriff (Cobb Vanth) lowers the targeting mechanism and fires the missile from his jetpack. From his perspective, you can see a targeting display. Once the target is acquired, he fires the missile. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you confirm which episode? Or provide a screenshot?

Comment: ScreenRant goes into this subject and also have a screenshot from the series: https://screenrant.com/mandalorian-boba-fett-helmets-targeting-sight-difference-explained/

Comment: Mando's helmet doesn't have one of these. The scene you're thinking of was done using Boba Fett's suit, when it was worn first by a Sheriff who had bought it from Jawas, and then a later scene where's it's worn by Fett himself.